# Fastai predict on collaboative learning model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

I have a Fast ai collaborative filtering model. I would like to predict on this model for a new tuple.
I am having trouble with the predict function

From their documentation,

```
Signature: learn.predict(item, rm_type_tfms=None, with_input=False)
Docstring: Prediction on `item`, fully decoded, loss function decoded and probabilities
File:      ~/playground/virtualenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/fastai/learner.py
Type:      method
```

How do I define the Item that I need to pass. Lets say for a movielens dataset, for a user already with in the dataset, we would like to recommend a set of movies, how do we pass the userID?

I have tried to follow somewhat of an answer here - https://forums.fast.ai/t/making-predictions-with-collaborative-filtering/3900

learn.predict( [np.array([3])] )

I seem to get an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list`

Answer (score 2):

I think this will help:
https://medium.com/@igorirailean/a-recommender-system-using-fastai-in-google-colab-110d363d422f

The documentation also contains the following information:

```
dl = learn.dls.test_dl(test_df)
learn.get_preds(dl=dl)
```

It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `DataLoader` with the dataset you want predict for and pass it to the `get_preds` method. Let's say we want to predict the rating for movies with id's `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` for user id `1000`:

```
user_id = 1000
# you can substitute this with list of all movies user did not rate yet, to get full predictions
movies_to_predict_for = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

# create a dataframe with pairs [user_id, movie_id]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user': [user_id] * len(movies_to_predict_for),
    'item': movies_to_predict_for
})

# covert it to DataLoader and make predictions
dl = learn.dls.test_dl(df)
preds = learn.get_preds(dl=dl)

# merge predictions with movie ids
preds_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'item': movies_to_predict_for,
    'prediction': preds[0].numpy().flatten()
}).sort_values('prediction', ascending=False)

# show top 10 ratings
display(preds_df[:10])
```